# Password Question (only first couple of characters are used) > Gizmodo Situation

Tags: php, hash, salt

Ok so you know how Gnosis released gizmodo's passwords then said that their password system was so weak that all passwords could have been limited to first 8 characters and they would still work. Does that mean that if they put a 8+ character salt on it all passwords would have technically been the same (you can logg in with anything).

So that brought me to the question:

Do password hashs use all of the string or only a portion of it?

So is password placement with the salt important? salt + pass or pass + salt ?

Will putting a salt length after a certain number of characters mess things up?

Thanks!

(I am using ripemd if it matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes will use the whole string.  They were cutting it to save time in processing (maybe?).

It doesnt matter where you put the salt, beggining or end, just make sure its complex enough.

Comment: http://intrepidusgroup.com/insight/2010/12/gawker-des-crypt-fun-using-john-the-ripper-with-mpi/ Turns out they used DES sans salt. Ok thats reassuring. Hahses use the whole string not just parts of it. Thanks